# C-H Bond Dissociation Energy varies with substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, stability

What is the reason behind it?

"Among sp3 hybridized systems, methane has the strongest C-H bond. C-H bonds on primary carbons are stronger than those on secondary carbons, which are stronger than those on tertiary carbons."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nature always try to acheive least potential energy for stability . Any organic reaction which makes the product less stable is not favourable .

If the C-H bonds are cleaved homolytically in all cases , the resulting stability of the free radicals will tell us about the feasibility of the reaction .

The primary free radical is the most unstable and to bring about its C-H bond breaking would mean increasing its energy comparitively . Hence its bond energy is the most and so its the stronger bond of the three .

Tertiary free radical is the most stable while secondary lies in between them . The same explanation can be used to draw out their comparitive strength of the C-H bonds .

Comment: Bond dissociation energy is defined based on homolytic cleavage, so you can't use carbocation stability as a rationale (although it turns out that the trend is the same).

Comment: @jerepierre does the free radical so formed follow the logic ?